# Regular Expressions + Including one space in pattern

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, function, output

I'm trying to figure out how to write a pattern to match to the following: "3Z 5Z".  The numbers in this can vary, but the Z's are constant.  The issue I'm having is trying to include the white space... Currently I have this as my pattern

```
 pattern = @"\b*Z\s*Z\b";
```

The '*' represent the wildcard for the number preceding the "Z", but it doesn't seem to want to work with the space in it. For example, I can use the following pattern successfully for matching to the same thing without the space (i.e. 3Z5Z)

```
pattern = @"\b*Z*Z\b";
```

I am writing this program in .NET 4.0 (C#).  Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: This pattern is part of a larger string, for example:
3Z 10Z lock 425"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern = @"\b\d+Z\s+\d+Z\b";
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
\b    # Assert position at a word boundary
\d    # Match a single digit 0..9
   +     # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Z     # Match the character “Z” literally
\s    # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +     # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d    # Match a single digit 0..9
   +     # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Z     # Match the character “Z” literally
\b    # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

By the way:

```
\b*
```

Should throw an exception. `\b` is a word anchor. You can't quantify it.

Comment: Hi FailedDev - thanks for the suggestion but it's still not returning  a Match.. Maybe you can spot a mistake - I now have:

pattern = @"\b\d+Z\s+\d+Z\b"; (edit - removed astrix but still does not work)

Comment: @keynesiancross **\d+*** this should also throw an exception. Remove the asterisk after the +.

Comment: Sorry - removed that astrix (see edit above) but still does not provide match...  Also added edit to OP

Comment: Turns out I'm just an idiot and was setting my breakpoint before the method runs.. You're code above works great.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="3Z 5Z";

      string re1="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1
      string re2="(Z)"; // Any Single Character 1
      string re3="( )"; // Any Single Character 2
      string re4="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 2
      string re5="(Z)"; // Any Single Character 3

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String int1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String c1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String c2=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            String int2=m.Groups[4].ToString();
            String c3=m.Groups[5].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+int1.ToString()+")"+"("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+c2.ToString()+")"+"("+int2.ToString()+")"+"("+c3.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It matches the Z's and any integers.

Comment: FYI, the `Singleline` option has no effect here.  All it does is allow the dot to match any character *including linefeed*, and there are no linefeeds in this regex.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to other posts I would add characters of the Begin and End of string.

```
patter = "^\d+Z\s\d+Z$"
```

Comment: True but OP had word anchors, so probably this string is part of a bigger string.